# NSRegularExpression validate email

Tags: ios, regex, cocoa

i want to use the `NSRegularExpression` Class to validate if an `NSString` is an email address.

Something like this pseudocode:

```
- (BOOL)validateMail : (NSString *)email
{
    NSRegularExpression *expression = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:NULL];

    if(emailValidated)
    {
        return YES;
    }else{
        return NO;
    }
}
```

But i don't know how exactly i validate an NSString if it's looking like this one "email@stackoverflow.com"

Perhaps someone can help me here.

Greetings
s4lfish

Comment: Sometimes all you need is simple `^[^@]+@[^@]+\.[^@]+$`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can use:

```
@"^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$";    // Edited: added ^ and $
```

you can test it here:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/?2rhq7

And save this link it will help you with Regex in the future:

http://gskinner.com/RegExr/

**EDIT**

You can do it this way:

```
 NSString *string = @"shlaflaf@me.com";
 NSString *expression = @"^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$"; // Edited: added ^ and $
 NSError *error = NULL;

    NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:expression options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];

    NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];

    if (match){
         NSLog(@"yes");
    }else{
         NSLog(@"no");
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but my problem is that i don't find a function to prove that the entered email fits the regex. I've looked in the documentation of apple, but somehow NSRegularExpression doesn't have a function which returns a boolean value for my "if-statement".

Comment: Hi I have added a code sample for that. And BTW @Alex Nichol it will be great if you could explain your comment. I might be wrong in my answer but your comment dose not help me or any one else understand this issue better.

Comment: That expression is not RFC 822 compliant.

Comment: You've forgotten to escape the "\"s in your pattern. `@"\."` in an NSRegularExpression pattern gets interpreted as "." -- in other words it matches *any* character. If your intention is to match only the literal ".", you need @"\\."

Answer (score 9):

This was an older question, but it's general enough to never go out of style.

**99.9% of email address regexs are wrong and even fewer handle international domains (IDN) properly.**

Trying to make a comprehensive email regex isn't a good use of development time or user CPU cycles.

This is much simpler:

1. Match `[^@]+@([^@]+)`
2. Extract the domain per the matched part.
3. Fail if it matches a banned domain.  Cache the list of banned domains locally from a JSON endpoint so you don't have to wait for re-approval and can update it on-the-fly.  (Be sure to log web stats for conversion analysis.)
4. Check that the domain has DNS records.  Check A and AAAA, in addition to MX, because not all domains implement MX. (Lame but true.)
5. Just try to send the email already.  The user will try again if they perceive an app has value. :))

Comment: agree, Top-level domain can more than 4, such as `community`, `properties`. over strict is worse than nothing.

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4 version**

I'm writing this for those who are doing Swift 4 version for email regular expression.
The above can be done as follows:

```
 do {
        let emailRegex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: "^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$", options: .caseInsensitive)
        let textRange = NSRange(location: 0, length: email.count)
        if emailRegex.firstMatch(in: email, options: [], range: textRange) != nil {
            //Do completion code here
        } else {
            //Do invalidation behaviour
        }
    } catch  {
         //Do invalidation behaviour
    }
```

Assuming email is a swift String typed.