# Extract value from NSString with NSRegularExpression

Tags: ios, regex, nsregularexpression

I have the following NSString:

```
var param1=8;
var param2=4;
var param3=1;
```

from which I need to extract the values of the params. I use the NSRegularExpression but cannot have it working:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"var param1=(.*);\nvar param2=(.*);\nvar param3=(.*)" options:0 error:NULL];
NSTextCheckingResult *match = [regex firstMatchInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
NSString *param1= [match rangeAtIndex:1];
```

Comment: I had a crash when trying that

Answer (score 1):

while the title doesn't do justice to the answer, the question [NSRegularExpression validate email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198303/nsregularexpression-validate-email) supplies a link to a useful online [regex checker](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) .

my sense is that you are having trouble with the \n character in the regex in your example.

i would consider an expression such as `@"^var param[123]=\b(\w*)\b;"`, which should provide you three matches; you'll have to use `NSRegularExpression` method `matchesInString` instead of `firstMatchInString`, but your loop should be pretty simple:

```
    NSArray* matches = [regex matchesInString:string
                                      options:0
                                        range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])];
    for (NSTextCheckingResult *match in matches) {
        // per match processing
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you're casting NSRange into NSString, last line should look like:

```
NSString *param1= [string substringWithRange:[match rangeAtIndex:1]];
```

And secondly, maybe something's wrong with your string? It could have white spaces before newline, etc. I've tested:

```
NSString *string = @"var param1=8;\n"
                    "var param2=4;\n"
                    "var param3=1;";
```

and it's working fine, returning an '8'.