# How to check if text field contains roman numerals

Tags: iphone, ios, uitextfield

Are there any methods available to check whether a **UITextField** contains **roman numerals** like i,ii,iii,iv...etc???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing you can do (but maybe there are some other solution) is to check the UITextField string for those letter :

```
Bool find = NO;
NSArray *romans = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"i", @"ii", @"ii", @"vi", nil]; //Fill the array as you want

for(NSString *str in romans)
{
  if([textField.text rangeOfString:str].location != NSNotFound)
  {
    find = YES;
    break;
  }
}

if(find)
{
  //Roman letter found
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works fine for a quick solution. But got to look for an approach thats gonna help in the long run

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression through [`NSRegularExpression`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) in any of the `UITextFieldDelegate` methods to check if your `UITextField` has a valid roman number. You can see an example of use of `NSRegularExpression` in: [NSRegularExpression validate email](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8198303/nsregularexpression-validate-email)

Your regex should be something like the one posted in:
[How do you match only valid roman numerals with a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267399/how-do-you-match-only-valid-roman-numerals-with-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

Use `Regex` + [NSPredicate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html)

```
-(BOOL)isValidForRoman:(NSString *)text
{
    NSString *romanRegex = @"^(?=.)(?i)M*(D?C{0,3}|C[DM])(L?X{0,3}|X[LC])(V?I{0,3}|I[VX])$";
    NSPredicate *romanTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", romanRegex]; 
    return ([romanTest evaluateWithObject:text]);
}
```

This `Regex` is for `Roman` validation.