# Swift Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool' error with if let statement

Tags: swift

So i am coding an app in Xcode and this is a part of the code:

```
func Signup(_ sender: Any) {
        if let email = Email.text != nil, let password =
```

In the 2nd line i get a error

> Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not 'Bool'

Can you help me please?

Comment: Get rid of the `!= nil`.

Comment: BTW - It is standard practice that variable and function names start with lowercase letters. Class and struct names start with uppercase letters.

Comment: Btw The textfield never returns nil. The comparison against nil will always fail. Even if you assign nil to the text property and get its value right after it returns an empty string which is its default value. Considering this you can just force unwrap it `let emailText = email.text!`

Comment: If you are coding for iOS 10 or later and need to know if the text field is empty or not you can use UIKeyInput protocol method hasText https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uikeyinput/1614457-hastext in your case `if email.hasText {`

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, you should eliminate that `!= nil`.

I’d also recommend:

- trimming whitespace so someone doesn’t enter space to get past the validation;
- use `isEmpty` of the trimmed string to make sure there’s something there;
- start properties and method names with lowercase letters;
- I personally give my `UITextField` properties a `TextField` suffix (so I can distinguish the `emailTextField` text field from the `email` string.

Thus, perhaps something like:

```
@IBAction func didTapSignup(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        !email.isEmpty,
        let password = passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        !password.isEmpty else {
            // tell the user that validation failed here ...

            // ... and then return
            return
    }

    // do something with `email` and `password`
}
```

---

You might want to check, for example, that the email and password pass some rudimentary rules:

```
let emailRegexString = "^[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$"  // oversimplified email regex

func isAcceptable(email: String, password: String) -> Bool {
    let isEmailAcceptable = email.range(of: emailRegexString, options: .regularExpression) != nil
    let isPasswordAcceptable = password.count > 4

    return isEmailAcceptable && isPasswordAcceptable
}
```

And then

```
@IBAction func didTapSignup(_ sender: Any) {
    guard let email = emailTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        let password = passwordTextField.text?.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces),
        isAcceptable(email: email, password: password) else {
            // tell the user that validation failed here ...

            // ... and then return
            return
    }

    // do something with `email` and `password`
}
```

Note, that regex is a grossly [over-simplified email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8198402/1271826). But you can [go nuts on the regex](https://stackoverflow.com/a/201378/1271826) if you really want.

---

I’d also, at a bare minimum, set up my email and password text fields so that spaces are not allowed. So, specify the `delegate` for the email and password text fields and then prohibit spaces:

```
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        return string.rangeOfCharacter(from: .whitespacesAndNewlines) == nil
    }

}
```